# Problem w/Register-ScheduledTask in Powershell v5.1

Tags: xml, powershell, scheduled-tasks

Ok, I have the following code which retrieves a file from my main machine makes an adjustment and then creates a Scheduled Task on my test machine.
The program is run from the test machine. This works just as it should.

```
$SRCXMLPath = "\\Dellxps8920\BEKDocs-DellXPS8920\TaskSchedulerExports\Tasks"
$DestXMLPath = "G:\BEKDocs\TaskSchedulerExports\Standard"
$XMLFile = "Backup Report.xml"

$GCArgs = @{Path = 
             $(Join-Path -Path $SRCXMLPath -ChildPath $XMLFile)}

[xml]$xml = Get-Content @GCArgs

$xml.Task.RegistrationInfo.Author #Has no effect on running!

$xml.Task.Principals.Principal.UserId

<#+----------------------------------------------------+
  | Note: You can use either the text description of   |
  |       the account or the Registry designation.     |
  +----------------------------------------------------+
#>

$xml.Task.Principals.Principal.UserId = 
  'DellXPS8700\Bruce'

#  "S-1-5-21-1944453205-1635450679-2182824496-1001"

$xml.save()

& schtasks.exe /create /tn "Backup Report" /xml "$(Join-Path -Path $DestXMLPath -ChildPath $XMLFile)"
```

However, I'm trying to convert it to Full PowerShell via Register-ScheduledTask cmdlet to eliminate the call to schtasks.exe.
Using the following test code I consistently get the displayed error.

```
[xml]$Task = Get-Content "G:\BEKDocs\TaskSchedulerExports\Standard\Backup Report.xml"
$RTArgs = @{TaskName = "Backup Report"
            TaskPath = "\"
            XML      = $Task
            Force    = $True}

Register-ScheduledTask @RTArgs
```

Error Message:

```
Register-ScheduledTask @RTArgs
Register-ScheduledTask : The task XML is malformed.
(1,2)::ERROR: incorrect document syntax
At line:7 char:1
+ Register-ScheduledTask @RTArgs
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/. 
   ..S_ScheduledTask) [Register-ScheduledTask], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x8004131a,Register-ScheduledTask
```

Anyone have any Ideas?

Please Note: the .xml file works perfectly with the code at the top of the post or if it is imported manually inside TaskSheceuler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading the XML file as an XML object, but the cmdlet expects a string object.

```
Register-ScheduledTask
        [-Force]
        [[-Password] <String>]
        [[-User] <String>]
        [-TaskName] <String>
        [[-TaskPath] <String>]
        [-Xml] <String>
        [-CimSession <CimSession[]>]
        [-ThrottleLimit <Int32>]
        [-AsJob]
        [<CommonParameters>]
```

Change the line to read the file in as just one string and you should be all set.

```
$Task = Get-Content "G:\BEKDocs\TaskSchedulerExports\Standard\Backup Report.xml" -raw
```

Comment: BINGO! Thank you so much. I had noticed the [String] in the help file and tried to convet using the ToString method but that didn't work. The -raw parameter was the key!